# Почему Gulp теряет модули?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.
Есть чистый шаблон галпа, при `npm i` он теряет 2-3 модуля, скажем не устанавливает `minify`,`uglify`,`notify` хотя в жсоне все зависимости прописаны, а он их не хочет устанавливать, проблема решается повторным `npm i` и он подтягивает недостающие модули.

[Ссылка на сам шаблон.](https://github.com/KucherenkoZZZ/Gulp)

P.S нода последняя, апдейт плагинов делал - не помогло

Comment: Это скорее проблема npm, а не gulp. npm отвечает за установку модулей.

Comment: Весь код должен содержаться в **самом вопросе**. Внешние ссылки могут стать нерабочими (что и произошло), тогда вопрос потеряет смысл!